# Turn off gzip for a location in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, php-fpm, gzip

How can gzip be turned off for a particular location and all its sub-directories? My main site is at `http://mydomain.com` and I want to turn gzip off for both `http://mydomain.com/foo` and `http://mydomain.com/foo/bar`. `gzip` is turned on in `nginx.conf`.

I tried turning off `gzip` as shown below, but the Response Headers in Chrome's dev tools shows that `Content-Encoding:gzip`.

How should gzip/output buffering be disabled properly?

**Attempt**:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mydomain/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        gzip on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location /foo/ {
        gzip off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }

}
```

---

### UPDATE

I turned off `gzip` in `nginx.conf` and tried using named locations. However gzip is now always off, and `gzip on;` in the `location /` block does not seem to turn gzip back on. Any ideas?

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mydomain/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    location /foo/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php_nogzip;
    }

    location @php {
        gzip on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }

    location @php_nogzip {
        gzip off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your application compressing its response?

Comment: Sorry for a newb question, but how does my application (running on PHP framework Laravel) compress the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suppose that URLs you're requesting are being handled with `try_files` inside `location ^~ /foo/` and due to absence of those files, they're internally re-directed to another `location` handler not having `gzip off` inherited.

Try using "named location" in `/foo` location, and then define that "named" location `@fooNoGzip` with `gzip off` inside and `fascgi_pass` stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggested and updated the original post with the new conf, but now gzip if always turned off. Can you take a look? :)

Comment: @Nyxynyx, solved?

Comment: This helped me. gzip was the right solution.

Comment: This helped me. Turning off gzip was the right solution. However the down side is that it applied to all *.php.  So,  text/html for all php processed pages are not compressed. We do have CDN over Varnish which will cache pages for lower TTL and that does the Gzip at last mile.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of some necro-romancy: the updated nginx configuration of the OP wasn't working because it's handled ultimately by `\.php$` location block.

The proper solution would be removing it and making the named locations as the ones forwarding requests to FastCGI (PHP-FPM):

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mydomain/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    location /foo/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php_nogzip;
    }

    location @php {
        gzip on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location @php_nogzip {
        gzip off;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As each location is independent, setting `gzip off` on `@php_nogzip` will not apply to the `location ~ \.php$`, it still use the nginx/server default. That is why you see gzip off, because that is the default. Only files delivered by the try_files in the `@php_nogzip` will be compressed.

The only way i see is to use the map. In the http block use:

```
map $uri   $gz {
   default  "on";
    ~/foo/  "off";
}
```

Then in the server:

```
   location ~ \.php$ {
        gzip $gz; 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }
```

Comment: This will never work. The `gzip` configuration directive only allows to be set in configuration directly and is not evaluated from a string variable produced by `map`.

Comment: @DanilaVershinin i never tested this, but if gzip do not accept variables and you need this, i would suggest open a bug in nginx, they are always adding support for more variable settings and this one looks like it would be useful for some people

Comment: I was merely communicating the fact that the `gzip` directive does not support variable expansion so your solution wouldn't work. I don't have such a requirement, and it's trivial to solve by adding proper locations, so I highly doubt nginx will ever will or need to add variable support for this directive, considering all the extra code required and maintaining it. E.g. exra code it is in my ngx_dynamic etag module's [change](https://github.com/dvershinin/ngx_dynamic_etag/commit/cb4b2847cb789084926520e1e97d7573011bf5f7) to support variable expansion for a similar `on/off` switch.